# for any infinite set A, |A| >= |N|

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I try to prove that the power of any infinite set must be equal/bigger then the power of the natural א0.

I tried to show that for any infinite set there exists a subset of it, that its power is the power of the naturals.

Comment: What is your definition of "infinite"?

Comment: I think he/she means countably infinite.